# Merging two files after checking that some of the columns match

Tags: shell-script, shell

Let's assume that I have two files 912300001.file1.txt and file2.txt and they contain the following:

912300001.file1.txt

```
VALUE   1000    -21 -21
VALUE   1001    -23 -22
VALUE   1002    -23 -21
```

First column is not important, second column is the counter that is present in both files, which is one of the columns that I want to check for when merging. Third and fourth columns are the ones that I want to merge.

file2.txt

```
-123456.12 -1234567.12 912300001     1000 123.1 123.1 ab 1 3
-123466.12 -1234667.12 912300001     1001 133.1 124.1 ab 2 2
-123476.12 -1234767.12 912300001     1002 143.1 125.1 ab 3 1
-123486.12 -1234867.12 922300001     1000 153.1 126.1 ab 3 1
-123496.12 -1234967.12 922300001     1001 163.1 127.1 ab 2 2
-123446.12 -1234367.12 922300001     1002 173.1 128.1 ab 1 3
```

I want to use the third column e.g. "912300001" to compare with the number in the name of the first file and the counter "1000" to the counter in the first file. If both match, I want to copy the value from columns 3 and 4 in the first file to the second one such that this happens:

output.txt

```
-123456.12 1234567.12 912300001     1000 123.1 123.1 ab 1 3 -21 -21
-123466.12 1234667.12 912300001     1001 133.1 124.1 ab 2 2 -23 -22
-123476.12 1234767.12 912300001     1002 143.1 125.1 ab 3 1 -23 -21
-123486.12 1234867.12 922300001     1000 153.1 126.1 ab 3 1 Values from
-123496.12 1234967.12 922300001     1001 163.1 127.1 ab 2 2 other files
-123446.12 1234367.12 922300001     1002 173.1 128.1 ab 1 3 will come in here
```

If possible as well, I would like to provide the list of files that it should check in an external file e.g. "list.txt".

Thanks,

---

EDIT: Solution was provided by reddit users: commandlineluser and ropid in this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/6evp5q/merging_two_files_after_checking_that_some_of_the/). The solution is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

{
    read -r line
    read -r _ _ prev_name prev_count _ <<< "$line"

    declare -A lookup
    while read -r _ key value
    do
        lookup[$key]=$value
    done < <( sed '$a\' "$prev_name.file1.txt" )

    echo "$line ${lookup[$prev_count]}"

    while read -r line
    do
        read -r _ _ name count _ <<< "$line"
        [[ $name != $prev_name ]] && {
            lookup=()
            while read -r _ key value
            do
                lookup[$key]=$value
            done < "$name.file1.txt"
        }
        prev_name=$name
        prev_count=$count
        echo "$line ${lookup[$prev_count]}"
    done
} < file2.txt
```

Thanks,